# Best practices for tracking a custom object's event stream

Tags: custom-object, stagename

I have a custom object that I am developing a staged progression for.
For the sake of easy discussion, let's just go ahead and call this `Object object` which has a picklist field `Object Stage`.

I have so far been tracking the progression through this stage by stamping the datetimes directly on the record like so:

```
stage_1_dt__c = '2020-01-15T15:55:55.000+0000'
stage_2_dt__c = '2020-01-11T11:11:11.000+0000'
stage_3_dt__c = <null>
```

etc.

Which is just messy in my opinion. It also

I'm thinking of converting this instead to a separate custom object `Object events` which, each record would be a child of the parent `Object object` and would have *usually* have a 1-1 association to the stages. The main benefit to handling things this way is that I want to make a timeline because an `Object object` record can move back and forth along the `Object stage` "progress bar". But I'd like to see those stage movements all from one datetime field instead of trying to recreate them across a datetime field for each `Object stage` + field history.

Open to any and all suggestions.

Comment: Field history object is basically similar to your proposed custom object solution. And you mentioned 6-7 fields, what are these fields for?

Comment: It is but I've found field history difficult to work with outside of apex and unfortunately, my solution has to be directly soql compatible to the easiest degree possible. So doing a relational join via soql should be fairly easy. Clarified the question to address your 6-7 fields (that was related to the # of datetime fields that correspond to each stage for tracking when it entered that stage)

Comment: If you track the history for Stage field, every time it is changed, it would create a new history record. So I think you should be able to query like this `SELECT NewValue, CreatedDate FROM ObjectHistory WHERE Field = 'Stage' ORDER BY CreatedDate`. Or did I misunderstand your point?

Comment: That's useful - what if I wanted to track over kinds of "events" that happen to this record besides that one field change. Which would include things like `Object object` creation, related task creation, field changes like movements through the stage, but also other "types" of events besides just field changes.

Comment: Object creation is always tracked by default if you enable the history tracking for the object. Would you consider using Feed Tracking feature? It can track Tasks/Events and all the related objects.